# Call external functions from multiple PowerShell scripts in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

I have a C# application that runs PowerShell scripts after reading them off database as strings.  Assume `script1`, `script2` and `utilityfunctions` are scripts read from database.

```
var rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
rs.Open();
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = rs;
ps.AddScript(utilityFunctions);
ps.AddScript(script1);
```

Is there anyway possible that I can call functions in `utilityFuntions` from `script1`? I have tried using `$MyInvocation` and go through its properties but did not find anything useful.  When going through `ps.Commands` properties, I can of course see two items but when going through commands within the script, I cannot get to anything inside `utilityFunctions`.  I guess I can read all scripts and concatenate them as string and only pass one script but I am just wondering if there is a way to do it without string concatenation.

Comment: Can't you just call your functions in script1. If you try a get-childItem function: what do you get ?

Comment: @JPBlanc I get list of files in my bin folder: EXE, .config and DLLs

Comment: Update: I have not been able to find a way to do this. So I have been concatenating strings. This is making debugging and error handling painful as I get a line# from logs but then have to put together all scripts called in one file to get to that line.